WPF: TextBox Background Property not working properly
I am working at a WPF project atm. It runs on .Net Framework 4.8 and we are using Telerik.
I have had the problem that I could not set the background color of a textBox Element in code.
textbox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
Had no effect, but worked on a naked sample WPF project.
I then built this method which worked:
private void SetTextboxBackground(TextBox textbox, SolidColorBrush brush)
{
    ControlTemplate template = new ControlTemplate(typeof(TextBox));

    FrameworkElementFactory border = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Border));
    border.SetValue(Border.BackgroundProperty, new TemplateBindingExtension(TextBox.BackgroundProperty));
    border.SetValue(Border.BorderBrushProperty, new TemplateBindingExtension(TextBox.BorderBrushProperty));
    border.SetValue(Border.BorderThicknessProperty, new TemplateBindingExtension(TextBox.BorderThicknessProperty));

    FrameworkElementFactory scrollViewer = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ScrollViewer));

    scrollViewer.Name = "PART_ContentHost";
    scrollViewer.SetValue(ScrollViewer.BackgroundProperty, brush); 

    border.AppendChild(scrollViewer);

    template.VisualTree = border;

    textbox.Template = template;

}

For clarification, the project is a type of scheduler which renders different components.
Now I had the problem, that whenever this method was run trough (at this code line: scrollViewer.Name = "PART_ContentHost";), the scheduler's scrollviewer jumped to the top.
When I checked the visual Tree, I noticed that the structure of the TextBox is quite a bit different to my minimal test project. Notably, there is one additional Border component right inside the outer ScrollViewer component for some reason.
Main project visual tree

Sample project visual tree

The border is there where the red line is in the attached picture.
Anybody of you had similar problems?
I have no idea what prevents the .Background from working and appreciate any help.
Thx and regards
